# Capistrano is throwing a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, deployment, rvm, capistrano, rbenv

I've been using Ruby's Capistrano deployment tool for a few years and never had much problems with it at all. Now, after upgrading Ruby to 2.0, I started getting all kinds of errors making it impossible for me to deploy.

I've since totally uninstalled RVM and everything but my base OS X Ruby install (1.8.7 I believe) and then re-installed from scratch via rbenv.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3-p0 via rbenv, and have installed Capistrano gem version 2.15.4 -- but every time I try to do a dry run deploy `cap -n deploy` from a small, default Capfile/deploy.rb setup, I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb:234:in `block in query_revision': undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

My Capfile is just the default from running `$ capify .`

```
# Capfile

load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

And config/deploy.rb is incredibly simple:

```
set :application, "capistrano-example"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/jasonrhodes/capistrano-example.git"

set :scm, 'git'

set :user, "myusername"
set :deploy_to, "/home/myusername/jrhodes.me/public_html/capistrano-example"
set :domain, "myserver.com"
role :web, domain              # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain              # This may be the same as your `Web` server
```

Any ideas where this error is coming from???

Comment: I, too, have encountered this error recently, and I have yet to decipher where it came from. You don't have to have force-pushed your branch recently, have you?

Comment: i have the same error. only in dry-runs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help you, but I traced this back to my installation of the [railsless-deploy](https://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy/) gem. It seems, even if it isn't required, that it still somehow was being loaded in and interfering w/ Cap's built-in `load 'deploy'`, and causing all sorts of havoc (since you can't have railsless-deploy and Cap's built-in deploy namespace together).

Anyway, I removed the `load 'deploy'` line, added in railsless-deploy, and all has been well.

Comment: It’s been a while, but I’ll point out that I’m now the maintainer of the railsless-deploy gem. So, if it causes more trouble, lemme know with an issue over there!