# Capistrano error when using git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to setup capistrano and want to test my config locally before testing on the server, but when I run cap deploy -n keep getting the following error relating to git

```
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@wgbh/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb:234:in `block in query_revision': undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

and leading up to this as follows:

```
  * 2013-08-26 12:12:30 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-08-26 12:12:30 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-08-26 12:12:30 executing `deploy:update_code'
  * executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:GIT_REPO GIT_BRANCH"
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /u/apps/APP_NAME/releases/20130826161230; true"
```

I have tried to trace this back, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.  My deploy.rb looks as follows:

```
require "bundler/capistrano" 

set :application, "APP_NAME"
set :deply_to, "/the/server/path"
set :user, "SERVER_USER"

set :repository,  "git@github.com:GIT_REPO_PATH"
set :scm, :git
set :scm_username , "GIT_USER_NAME"
#this allows you to choose a branch in the command line or default to master with 'cap -S branch=branchname deploy'
set :branch, fetch(:branch, "master")

#tells is to do resuse a single remote git clone
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

server "THE_SERVER_NAME", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:migrate'

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

Has anyone else experienced this error? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498099/capistrano-is-throwing-a-nomethoderror) but following the one suggestion does not change the error at all.

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to be that when in dry run mode the run_locally function returns an array, not the expected string.

See 
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L133

Not sure if there is an easy way for the git recipe to figure out that it is in dry run mode. If you just hack in something like this:

```
# in recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb ~line 229
result = yield(command)
return "666" if result.class == Array  # better would be: dry_run?
```

Then the -n invocation continues.

Comment: There is a pull request in capistrano that starts to address this.    https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/464

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the referenced error:

```
      command = scm('ls-remote', repository, revision)
      result = yield(command)
      revdata = result.split(/[\t\n]/)
      newrev = nil
      revdata.each_slice(2) do |refs|
        rev, ref = *refs
        if ref.sub(/refs\/.*?\//, '').strip == revision.to_s # Explosion!
        ...
      end
```

It seems likely no revision data is being loaded for the selected branch or repository (`ref` is nil when `sub` is called on it). Try running the specified command yourself (`git ls-remote git@github.com:GIT_REPO GIT_BRANCH`) which should hopefully generate a more specific error message, probably involving the branch or the repository itself.

Comment: Running that command returns 0a6f2b064a09ff2963e970440a81cef976f94c5a refs/heads/development so it seems that its getting the right revision info